# Network Router stops resolving client name after a while

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns, workgroup

I am running a simple 3 computer windows 10 wirelessly linked network through a Bell router. All works well for a while (days) and then suddenly one computer is unable to access the other computers by name. That is I can ping the computers by ip address without problems, but not by name.  HoweverIPScanner still finds all computers without problems. I can regain connection by resetting the wifi adapter or the router without problems, but after some more time the problem reoccurs. The problem happens at random from any of the 3 computers at random. Any ideas?
I have tried all of the obvious solutions without success. THe only recourse left is to assign static IP addresses but that seems to be a workaroud.

Answer (score 0):

Log into the Bell Router and see if you can match MAC address with IP address (a form of DHCP reservation). If you can do this, you can keep DHCP on your computers but they will have the same IP. Devices like Phones like to grab IP addresses and probably the computers are constantly changing their IP addresses (which plays havoc with Client Names).

I use this method (DHCP reservation) for my main computer in my small network and it works really well. I suggest you see if you can implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Not so simple..... Yes router index table is fine.  That is all devices, IP addresses and names show perfectly. Also IPScanner runiing on any of the clients shows all clients and router correctly. DHCP is running on all computers and shows communication to the router in independent DHCP tests. All computers are running the same version of Windows 10 with the same updates. Really strange thing is that when one client1 for example cannot resolve client2, client2 can still resolve client1. Also at any time I can regain name resolution by reseting the client's wifi adapter or by restarting the router. I am currently trying to analyse DHCP communications. Something strange appears to be going on there. When all is well DHCP discovery to the router returns "offer". when things are not working DHCP returns "ack". Not sure this is significant or not.